# Set the active document in word to readonly

Tags: c#, ms-word

I'm using the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word to manipulate the documents, things like creating a new document based on a template.

The only problem I'm having is to set the active document in Word to readonly. Keeping in mind that I open a new document based on a template, fill some fields with the necessary information, then a need to show this document to the user as readonly. This document still in memory (Doesn't have a path).

The library have a readonly attribute, but is readonly (Oh the irony...). Anybody have any suggestions that might help me?

Comment: Once you've created the document and filled in the necessary fields, save it.  Then reopen it as readonly and show to the user.

Comment: @ChrisLively I tried that solution and it worked, but I wish to implement something without using this method. Something more dynamic.

Comment: Unless word can "open" a document that's already in memory there really isn't another way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Read-only` is one of the defining features of the `Document` and thus it has to be set when the `Document` is created (added to the `Application`). Sample code:

```
bool readOnly = true;
Object templatePath = @"Path";
Object oMissing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
Word.Application wordApp = new Word.Application();
Word.Document wordDoc = wordApp.Documents.Open(templatePath, oMissing, readOnly, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing);
```

Comment: I know I can to this, but I wish to set this property while the document is opened. I think that there must be some other way to prevent the user from editing the document without saving the document, then re-opening.

Comment: @Albert as said, there is no other way. You can intend to come up with a custom approach avoiding information to be written (e.g., being automatically deleted), but the implementation might become difficult and the final performance will rarely be good enough. The ReadOnly property is ironically (,as you rightly pointed out,) readonly and thus there is nothing you can do on this front. In any case, I don't think that there should be any problem: users would expect a (short) waiting period when the transition editable to readonly is performed.

Comment: Well, fair enough. I don't wish to spent more time on this if the only way is to create a more custom approach, I just thought that I was missing something. But thanks my good sir.